# Android Studio Flutter inspector not showing selected widget's source code on click

Tags: flutter, widget, inspector

In my previous laptop, When I select the toggle select widget mode and then select the click anywhere on the screen it scrolls to the selected widget in widget tree as well as it move to the source code of selected widget in editor.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPpTm.png)

But now I changed the laptop and installed new version of android studio, after selecting the toggle select widget mode when I tap on screen, the widget tree scrolls but my source code not moved to the specific widget. I am new to the given app and I can't find screens one by one manually.